# Removing elements from nodes or nodes from xml when attribute and text content match using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having difficulties transforming an xml. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <organisation>
        <school>
            <name>school of arts Berlin</name>
            <address>123street</address>
        </school>
    </organisation>
    <teachers>
        <wo_number>34A</wo_number>
        <publication>
            <date>14-09-2018</date>
            <name>J. doe</name>
        </publication>
        <teacher id="A254">
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="A254">
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="B254">
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="X92">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
        </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
    </teachers>
</root>
```

What i am trying to achieve:

- teacher element has an attribute id, if it starts with "A2" AND the text content of the element ill within the same teacher node equals to "yes" the situation node must be removed. if there are no situation nodes left in the teacher node, the teacher node must be removed
- teacher element has an attribute id, if it starts with "G5" AND the text content of the element ill within the same teacher node equals to "probable" the situation node must be removed. if there are no situation nodes left in the teacher node, the teacher node must be removed

the correct outcome should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <organisation>
        <school>
            <name>school of arts Berlin</name>
            <address>123street</address>
        </school>
    </organisation>
    <teachers>
        <wo_number>34A</wo_number>
        <publication>
            <date>14-09-2018</date>
            <name>J. doe</name>
        </publication>
        <teacher id="A254">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="B254">
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="X92">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
    </teachers>
</root>
```

so far i haven't been able to achive this. My xslt is now:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id,'A2') and situation/ill='yes']"/>
      <xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id,'G5') and situation/ill='probable']"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

with this outcome:

```
    <root>
        <organisation>
            <school>
                <name>school of arts Berlin</name>
                <address>123street</address>
            </school>
        </organisation>
        <teachers>
            <wo_number>34A</wo_number>
            <publication>
                <date>14-09-2018</date>
                <name>J. doe</name>
            </publication>


            <teacher id="B254">
                <situation>
                    <ill>probable</ill>
                </situation>
            </teacher>
            <teacher id="X92">
                <situation>
                    <ill>no</ill>
                </situation>
            </teacher>
            <teacher id="G56">
                <situation>
                    <ill>yes</ill>
                </situation>
            </teacher>

        </teachers>
    </root>
```

All teacher nodes with 
`id="A254"` are removed which is not correct and teacher nodes with `id="G56"` are removed which is also not correct.Some help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution requires a little fine tuning of the empty templates.

The first two templates check if the `teacher` element has all `yes` or `probable` values in `situation/ill` children and if so, remove them. The check is performed by comparing the count of the children to the count of the matching children.

The other two templates check for `situation` elements which have only one `ill` element containing a `yes` or `probable`. If so, only the `situation` element is removed and not the whole `teacher` element.

```
<xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id,'A2') and situation/ill='yes' and count(situation[ill='yes']) = count(situation/ill)]" />      
<xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id,'G5') and situation/ill='probable' and count(situation[ill='probable']) = count(situation/ill)]" />
<xsl:template match="situation[starts-with(../@id,'A2') and ill='yes']"/>      
<xsl:template match="situation[starts-with(../@id,'G5') and ill='probable']"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, as you are looking for an XSLT 2 solution chances are you use Saxon 9 or Altova where the latest releases also support XSLT 3 you can make use of the XSLT 3 `xsl:where-populated` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-where-populated to make sure only those `teacher` elements creating content with the processing of their children create output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id, 'A2')] | teacher[starts-with(@id, 'G5')]">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id, 'A2')]/situation[ill = 'yes'] |
                       teacher[starts-with(@id, 'G5')]/situation[ill = 'probable']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online demo at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJ9.

Comment: i have to use 2.0 but I tried your solution unfortunately it gave me 2 errors: XTSE0010: Element <xsl:mode> is not allowed as child of element <xsl:stylesheet>
XTSE0010: Element <xsl:where-populated> is not allowed as child of element <xsl:template>. i don't know why i get these errors your fiddle works fine

Comment: @fasln01, I think I clearly indicated that `xsl:where-populated` is a new feature in XSLT 3, I also explained which processors support that (latest versions of Saxon 9, which is currently 9.8, or of Altova, which is currently the 2018 release). So my answer was meant as an alternative in case you use those versions anyway. The XSLT Fiddle tool uses Saxon 9.8 HE so it supports XSLT 3.

Comment: Yes you were clear and i was aware of your intentions. I was eager to explore your solution, i used altova xmlspy with a 3.0 xslt template But apparently it doesn’t have the 2018 release. Thank You for your solution Martin

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:element name="organisation">
            <xsl:element name="school">
                <xsl:element name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="organisation/school/name"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="address">
                    <xsl:value-of select="organisation/school/address"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="teachers">
            <xsl:element name="wo_number">
                <xsl:value-of select="teachers/wo_number"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="publication">
                <xsl:element name="date">
                    <xsl:value-of select="teachers/publication/date"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="teachers/publication/name"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>


        <xsl:for-each select="teachers/teacher">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=" starts-with(@id,'A2')">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="situation/ill='no'">
                            <xsl:element name="teacher">
                                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>

                            <situation>
                                <xsl:element name="ill">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="situation[ill='no']"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </situation>
                            <situation>
                                <xsl:element name="ill">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="situation[ill='probable']"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </situation>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="situation/ill='yes'"/>
                    </xsl:choose>   
                </xsl:when>
                <!--<xsl:when test=" starts-with(@id,'A2') and situation/ill='yes'"/>-->

                <xsl:when test="starts-with(@id,'G5')">
                    <xsl:choose>

                        <xsl:when test="situation/ill='no'">
                            <xsl:element name="teacher">
                                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>

                                <situation>
                                    <xsl:element name="ill">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="situation[ill='no']"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </situation>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="situation/ill='yes'">
                            <xsl:element name="teacher">
                                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>

                                <situation>
                                    <xsl:element name="ill">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="situation[ill='yes']"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </situation>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="situation/ill='probable'"/>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```